# Image Upload : Base64 to server in post request or Express Js Middelware

Tags: node.js, image, express, base64, image-upload

I need to upload a local file to s3 and save its link in the database. Right now I am converting the image to base64 and sending it to my rails server, which saves it on s3 and returns a url. I send this URL in the next HTTP request. Now, how about  I save it via express get a link and then use it for the request. What be the better approach? Using middleware or backend server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file upload, i suggest you to use **multer** middleware, because native multipart implementation is a little bit tricky. For interaction with amazon  **s3** middleware is used.

To send file somewhere else you could use pipes:

```
fs.createReadStream(rqPath).pipe(res);
```

In above example, file is read from local system and piped to response.

All mentioned modules could be find at [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Comment: And it's the better approach righ? what about sending base64 in post request to rails server?

Comment: In my humble opinion, you don't have to convert file to binary-to-text encoding. Just get it in node and pipe it in all directions. On the RoR side, multipart/form-data will improve app performance. The best option to send file to RoR is this module http://npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0):

If you're still trying to figure this out, I was struggling with the same issue, decided to POST binary data (converted from base64) directly in body without dealing with multipart forms, and whipped up the [base64-image-upload](https://github.com/karan1149/base64-image-upload) package to make this easy.